# better looking variables names long tables

Tags: longtable

I want a suggestion for better looking at variables names

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
  \usepackage{natbib}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xfrac}
 \usepackage{longtable}
  \usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
 \usepackage{microtype}
 \usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{paralist}
   \usepackage{amsfonts}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
     \usepackage{pdflscape}

     \begin{document}

   \begin{landscape}
   \begin{table}[!ht]
   \begin{center}
     \caption{Baseline and Selected MEMs: Estimated Coefficients, July 2010–January 2020}
     \label{tab:table_detailed_occ_stats}
     \resizebox{1.34\textwidth}{!}{
     \begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccc}
     \toprule
     \toprule
        & \multicolumn{ 4}{c}{\textbf{HK}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{IN}} & \multicolumn{4} 
      {c}{\textbf{KO}}  \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
     \cmidrule(lr){6-9}
      \cmidrule(lr){10-13}
          & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{Baseline} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Selected} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c} 
  {Baseline} & \multicolumn{ 2}{c}{Selected} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Baseline} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Selected} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
         \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
         \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
         \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
         \cmidrule(lr){10-11}
             \cmidrule(lr){12-13}
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{t-statist}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{t-statist}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{t-statist}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{t-statist}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{t-statist}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{t-statist}\\
\cmidrule{2-13}


                 \rule{0pt}{3ex} $\omega$ &        0.031&        3.89&       0.05&        0.14&        0.31&        0.50&        0.03&        0.08&        0.25&        0.42&        0.03&        0.04\\
                 \rule{0pt}{3ex}$\mu_{t-1}$&       0.820&       0.31&        0.01&        0.01&        0.20&        0.35&        0.01&        0.02&        0.16&        0.28&        0.01&        0.01\\
             \rule{0pt}{3ex}$duringcovid_{t-1}$&        0.06&        0.11&        0.01&        0.02&        0.05&        0.09&        0.01&        0.01&        0.05&        0.08&        0.01&        0.01\\
             \rule{0pt}{3ex}$postcovid_{t-1}$&        0.00&        0.00&        0.02&        0.10&        0.00&        0.01&        0.01&        0.05&        0.00&        0.00&        0.01&        0.02\\

            \rule{0pt}{3ex}$hong kong_{t-1}$&        0.137&        0.07&        0.00&        0.00&        0.05&        0.06&        0.00&        0.00&        0.04&        0.05&        0.00&        0.00\\
           \hspace{0.5cm}$hong kong_{t-1}\times duringcovid_{t-1}$&   0.21 &0.11  &0.03 & 0.02&        0.20&        0.13&        0.03&        0.02&        0.18&        0.14&        0.02&        0.02\\

            \rule{0pt}{3ex}$indonesia_{t-1}$&        0.17&        0.06&        0.13&   0.04&       0.17&        0.11&        0.16&        0.08&        0.19&        0.18&        0.16&        0.14\\
              \hspace{0.5cm}$indonesia_{t-1}\times duringcovid_{t-1}$ &0.08& 0.01&0.05& 0.01&   0.09&        0.01&        0.04&        0.01&        0.12&        0.04&        0.06&        0.03\\


                 \rule{0pt}{3ex}$south korea_{t-1}$&        0.09&  0.01&  0.41&        0.19&     0.11&    0.02&   0.45&        0.27&        0.12&        0.06&        0.48&        0.34\\
       \hspace{0.5cm}$south korea_{t-1}\times duringcovid_{t-1}$& 0.00&  0.00&        0.20&     0.12&    0.00&   0.00&        0.22&        0.13&        0.00&        0.00&        0.23&        0.17\\


                       \rule{0pt}{3ex}$malaysia_{t-1}$&        0.00&   0.00&  0.05&        0.03&     0.00&    0.00&   0.06&        0.04&        0.00&        0.00&        0.07&        0.04\\
               \hspace{0.5cm}$malaysia_{t-1}\times duringcovid_{t-1}$&        0.08&        0.01&     0.15&    0.05&   0.11&        0.02&        0.18&        0.10&        0.12&        0.06&        0.18&        0.13\\

                  \rule{0pt}{3ex}$malaysia_{t-2}$&0.06 &0.01 &0.01 &0.00 & 0.07 &0.02 &0.01 &0.00 &0.08 &0.03 &0.00 &0.00\\
              \rule{0pt}{3ex}$philippines_{t-1}$&        0.01&          0.09&        0.25&0.45& 0.02&        0.08&        0.23&        0.45&        0.02&        0.06&        0.22&        0.39\\
           \hspace{0.5cm}$philippines_{t-1}\times DC_{t-1}$&         0.00&        0.00&0.04& 0.09&        0.00&        0.00&        0.04&        0.12&        0.00&        0.00&        0.05&        0.14\\


                  \rule{0pt}{3ex}$singapore_{t-1}$ &0.00  &0.00 &       0.06&        0.03&        0.00&        0.00&        0.05&        0.02&        0.00&        0.00&        0.03&        0.01\\
                        \hspace{0.5cm}$singapore_{t-1}\times duringcovid_{t-1}$&  0.00&    0.00&    0.04&    0.08&  0.00&   0.00&    0.03&   0.07&        0.00&        0.00&     0.03&     0.06\\
              \hspace{0.5cm}$singapore_{t-2}$&        0.01&    0.07&    0.03&        0.08&        0.01&        0.05&        0.04&        0.09&        0.02&     0.04&     0.03&     0.10\\


                              \rule{0pt}{3ex}$taiwan _{t-1}$&        0.01&    0.02&    0.08&        0.16&        0.01&        0.02&        0.08&        0.17&        0.01&     0.01&     0.07&     0.08\\
                              \hspace{0.5cm}$taiwan_\times duringcovid_{t-1}$& 0.04&    0.23&        0.07&        0.16&        0.03&        0.12&        0.05&        0.08&     0.04&     0.08&    0.03&   0.04\\

              \rule{0pt}{3ex}$thailand_{t-1}$ &0.00  &0.00 &       0.06&        0.03&        0.00&        0.00&        0.05&        0.02&        0.00&        0.00&        0.03&        0.01\\
                     \hspace{0.5cm}$thailand_{t-1}\times duringcovid_{t-1}$&  0.00&    0.00&    0.04&    0.08&  0.00&   0.00&    0.03&   0.07&        0.00&        0.00&     0.03&     0.06\\
          \hspace{0.5cm}$thailand_{t-2}$& 0.01&  0.07&    0.03&        0.08&        0.01&        0.05&        0.04&        0.09&        0.02&     0.04&     0.03&     0.10\\


               \rule{0pt}{3ex}$mk_{t-1}^{+}$& 0.01&  0.07&    0.03&        0.08&        0.01&        0.05&        0.04&        0.09&        0.02&     0.04&     0.03&     0.10\\
             \hspace{0.5cm}$mk_{t-1}^{+}\times duringcovid_{t-1}$& 0.01&  0.07&    0.03&        0.08&        0.01&        0.05&        0.04&        0.09&        0.02&     0.04&     0.03&     0.10\\
          \hspace{0.5cm}$mk_{t-1}^{-}\times duringcovid_{t-1}$& 0.01&  0.07&    0.03&        0.08&        0.01&        0.05&        0.04&        0.09&        0.02&     0.04&     0.03&     0.10\\

          \bottomrule
          \end{tabular}}%
         \end{center}
          \end{table}
         \end{landscape}
         \end{document}
```

`
[image]

Comment: Please, make your document example as MWE (Minimal Working Example), i.e. from preamble remove all noz to your problem related packages and add missed one (which enable landscape orientation of table).

Comment: @Zarko By adding \usepackage{pdflscape}, I could resolve the problem of margin, still don't find a way for a better presentation of variables!

Comment: As starting point: don't write state names in  math environments, try toreplace " duringcovid` with shortenes (and explain somewhere (in caption?) what it means. For example: `\hspace{0.5cm} hong kong$_{t-1}\times$ DC$_{t-1}$˙and explain that `DC` is shortens for `duringcovid`. More help I can provide late afternoon , now I have only short break at my work :-(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By use of `tabularray` package and consider my comment below question, the table can be designed as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}  % make text area bigger
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            hang,
            font=small, labelfont=bf, textfont=it]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\NewTableCommand\mcl{\SetCell[c=2]{l}}

\begin{document}
   \begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!ht]
   \small
\caption{Baseline and Selected MEMs: Estimated Coefficients, July 2010–January 2020}%
\label{tab:table_detailed_occ_stats}

\begin{tblr}{colsep=3pt,
             colspec = {@{} Q[l,wd=1em] l
                            X[c, si={table-format=1.3}]
                      *{11}{X[c, si={table-format=1.2}]} @{}},
            row{4-Z} = {rowsep = 0pt}
            }
    \toprule
    &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}  {{{HK}}}
            &   &   &    & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  {{{IN}}}
                            &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}  {{{KO}}}
                                            &   &   &       \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{3-6}
        \cmidrule[lr]{7-10}
            \cmidrule[l]{11-14}
    &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Baseline}}}
            &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Selected}}}
                    &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Baseline}}}
                            &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Selected}}}
                                    &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Baseline}}}
                                            &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Selected}}}
                                                    &       \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{3-4}\cmidrule[lr]{5-6}
        \cmidrule[lr]{7-8}\cmidrule[lr]{9-10}
            \cmidrule[l]{11-12}\cmidrule[lr]{13-14}
    &
        &   {{{Coef}}}
            &   {{{t-stat.}}}
                &   {{{Coef}}}
                    &   {{{t-stat.}}}
                        &   {{{Coef}}}
                            &   {{{t-stat.}}}
                                &   {{{Coef}}}
                                    &   {{{t-stat.}}}
                                        &   {{{Coef}}}
                                            &   {{{t-stat.}}}
                                                &   {{{Coef}}}
                                                    &   {{{t-stat.}}}   \\
    \cmidrule{3-14}
\mcl    $\omega$
    &   & 0.031 & 3.89  & 0.05  & 0.14  & 0.31  & 0.50
        & 0.03  & 0.08  & 0.25  & 0.42  & 0.03  & 0.04              \\
\mcl    $\mu_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.820 & 0.31  & 0.01  & 0.01  & 0.20  & 0.35
        & 0.01  & 0.02  & 0.16  & 0.28  & 0.01  & 0.01              \\
\mcl    duringcovid$_{t-1}$     (DC$_{t-1}$)
    &   & 0.06  & 0.11  & 0.01  & 0.02  & 0.05  & 0.09
        & 0.01  & 0.01  & 0.05  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.01              \\
\mcl    postcovid$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.02  & 0.10  & 0.00  & 0.01
        & 0.01  & 0.05  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.01  & 0.02              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    hong kong$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.137 & 0.07  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.05  & 0.06
        & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.04  & 0.05  & 0.00  & 0.00              \\
    &   hong kong$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.21  & 0.11  &0.03   & 0.02  & 0.20  & 0.13
        & 0.03  & 0.02  & 0.18  & 0.14  & 0.02  & 0.02              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    indonesia$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.17  & 0.06  & 0.13  & 0.04  & 0.17  & 0.11
        & 0.16  & 0.08  & 0.19  & 0.18  & 0.16  & 0.14              \\
    &   indonesia$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.05  & 0.01  & 0.09  & 0.01
        & 0.04  & 0.01  & 0.12  & 0.04  & 0.06  & 0.03              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    south korea$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.09  & 0.01  & 0.41  & 0.19  & 0.11  & 0.02
        & 0.45  & 0.27  & 0.12  & 0.06  & 0.48  & 0.34              \\
    &   south korea$_{t-1}\times$DC${t-1}$
        & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.20  & 0.12  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.22  & 0.13  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.23  & 0.17              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    malaysia$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.05  & 0.03  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.06  & 0.04  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.07  & 0.04              \\
    &   malaysia$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.15  & 0.05  & 0.11  & 0.02
        & 0.18  & 0.10  & 0.12  & 0.06  & 0.18  & 0.13              \\
    &   malaysia$_{t-2}$
        & 0.06  & 0.01  & 0.01  & 0.00  & 0.07  & 0.02
        & 0.01  & 0.00  & 0.08  & 0.03  & 0.00  & 0.00              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    philippines$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.01  & 0.09  & 0.25  & 0.45  & 0.02  & 0.08
        & 0.23  & 0.45  & 0.02  & 0.06  & 0.22  & 0.39              \\
    &   philippines$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.04  & 0.09  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.04  & 0.12  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.05  & 0.14              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    singapore$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.06  & 0.03  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.05  & 0.02  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.03  & 0.01              \\
    &   singapore$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.04  & 0.08  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.03  & 0.07  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.03  &   0.06            \\
    &   singapore$_{t-2}$
        & 0.01  & 0.07  & 0.03  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.05
        & 0.04  & 0.09  & 0.02  & 0.04  & 0.03  & 0.10              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    taiwan$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.01  & 0.02  & 0.08  & 0.16  & 0.01  & 0.02
        & 0.08  & 0.17  & 0.01  & 0.01  & 0.07  & 0.08              \\
    &   taiwan$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.04  & 0.23  & 0.07  & 0.16  & 0.03  & 0.12
        & 0.05  & 0.08  & 0.04  & 0.08  & 0.03  & 0.04              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    thailand$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.06  & 0.03  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.05  & 0.02  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.03  & 0.01              \\
    &   thailand$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.04  & 0.08  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.03  & 0.07  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.03  & 0.06              \\
    &   thailand$_{t-2}$
        & 0.01  & 0.07  & 0.03  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.05
        & 0.04  & 0.09  & 0.02  & 0.04  & 0.03  & 0.10              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    mk$_{t-1}^{+}$
    &   & 0.01  & 0.07  & 0.03  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.05
        & 0.04  & 0.09  & 0.02  & 0.04  & 0.03  & 0.10              \\
    &   mk$_{t-1}^{+}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.01  & 0.07  & 0.03  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.05
        & 0.04  & 0.09  & 0.02  & 0.04  & 0.03  & 0.10              \\
    &   mk$_{t-1}^{-}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.01  & 0.07  & 0.03  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.05
        & 0.04  & 0.09  & 0.02  & 0.04  & 0.03  & 0.10              \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
If you like marked some vaules with * or ** or ***, and add table note below table, than you need to change `tblr` to `talltblr` (or `longtblr` if table should be split between pages), in table preamble write notes (meaning of *, ** and ***) and mark selected values by `\TblrNote{**}`. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}  % make text area bigger
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            hang,
            font=small, labelfont=bf, textfont=it]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\NewTableCommand\mcl{\SetCell[c=2]{l}}

\begin{document}
   \begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!ht]
   \small
\caption{Baseline and Selected MEMs: Estimated Coefficients, July 2010–January 2020}%
\label{tab:table_detailed_occ_stats}

\begin{talltblr}[
note{} = {*:    $p<0.10$,\quad  % <---
          **:   $p<0.05$,\quad
          ***:  $p<0.01$.
          }
                ]{colsep=3pt,
             colspec = {@{} Q[l,wd=1em] l
                            X[c, si={table-format=1.3{**}}]
                      *{11}{X[c, si={table-format=1.2}]} @{}},
            row{4-Z} = {rowsep = 0pt}
            }
    \toprule
    &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}  {{{HK}}}
            &   &   &    & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  {{{IN}}}
                            &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}  {{{KO}}}
                                            &   &   &       \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{3-6}
        \cmidrule[lr]{7-10}
            \cmidrule[l]{11-14}
    &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Baseline}}}
            &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Selected}}}
                    &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Baseline}}}
                            &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Selected}}}
                                    &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Baseline}}}
                                            &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Selected}}}
                                                    &       \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{3-4}\cmidrule[lr]{5-6}
        \cmidrule[lr]{7-8}\cmidrule[lr]{9-10}
            \cmidrule[l]{11-12}\cmidrule[lr]{13-14}
    &
        &   {{{Coef}}}
            &   {{{t-stat.}}}
                &   {{{Coef}}}
                    &   {{{t-stat.}}}
                        &   {{{Coef}}}
                            &   {{{t-stat.}}}
                                &   {{{Coef}}}
                                    &   {{{t-stat.}}}
                                        &   {{{Coef}}}
                                            &   {{{t-stat.}}}
                                                &   {{{Coef}}}
                                                    &   {{{t-stat.}}}   \\
    \cmidrule{3-14}
\mcl    $\omega$
    &   & 0.031\TblrNote{*}
                & 3.89  & 0.05\TblrNote{**}
                                & 0.14  & 0.31\TblrNote{***}  % <---
                                                & 0.50
        & 0.03  & 0.08  & 0.25  & 0.42  & 0.03  & 0.04              \\
\mcl    $\mu_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.820 & 0.31  & 0.01  & 0.01  & 0.20  & 0.35
        & 0.01  & 0.02  & 0.16  & 0.28  & 0.01  & 0.01              \\
\mcl    duringcovid$_{t-1}$     (DC$_{t-1}$)
    &   & 0.06  & 0.11  & 0.01  & 0.02  & 0.05  & 0.09
        & 0.01  & 0.01  & 0.05  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.01              \\
\mcl    postcovid$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.02  & 0.10  & 0.00  & 0.01
        & 0.01  & 0.05  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.01  & 0.02              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    hong kong$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.137 & 0.07  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.05  & 0.06
        & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.04  & 0.05  & 0.00  & 0.00              \\
    &   hong kong$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.21  & 0.11  &0.03   & 0.02  & 0.20  & 0.13
        & 0.03  & 0.02  & 0.18  & 0.14  & 0.02  & 0.02              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    indonesia$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.17  & 0.06  & 0.13  & 0.04  & 0.17  & 0.11
        & 0.16  & 0.08  & 0.19  & 0.18  & 0.16  & 0.14              \\
    &   indonesia$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.05  & 0.01  & 0.09  & 0.01
        & 0.04  & 0.01  & 0.12  & 0.04  & 0.06  & 0.03              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    south korea$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.09  & 0.01  & 0.41  & 0.19  & 0.11  & 0.02
        & 0.45  & 0.27  & 0.12  & 0.06  & 0.48  & 0.34              \\
    &   south korea$_{t-1}\times$DC${t-1}$
        & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.20  & 0.12  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.22  & 0.13  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.23  & 0.17              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    malaysia$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.05  & 0.03  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.06  & 0.04  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.07  & 0.04              \\
    &   malaysia$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.15  & 0.05  & 0.11  & 0.02
        & 0.18  & 0.10  & 0.12  & 0.06  & 0.18  & 0.13              \\
    &   malaysia$_{t-2}$
        & 0.06  & 0.01  & 0.01  & 0.00  & 0.07  & 0.02
        & 0.01  & 0.00  & 0.08  & 0.03  & 0.00  & 0.00              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    philippines$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.01  & 0.09  & 0.25  & 0.45  & 0.02  & 0.08
        & 0.23  & 0.45  & 0.02  & 0.06  & 0.22  & 0.39              \\
    &   philippines$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.04  & 0.09  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.04  & 0.12  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.05  & 0.14              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    singapore$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.06  & 0.03  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.05  & 0.02  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.03  & 0.01              \\
    &   singapore$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.04  & 0.08  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.03  & 0.07  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.03  &   0.06            \\
    &   singapore$_{t-2}$
        & 0.01  & 0.07  & 0.03  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.05
        & 0.04  & 0.09  & 0.02  & 0.04  & 0.03  & 0.10              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    taiwan$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.01  & 0.02  & 0.08  & 0.16  & 0.01  & 0.02
        & 0.08  & 0.17  & 0.01  & 0.01  & 0.07  & 0.08              \\
    &   taiwan$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.04  & 0.23  & 0.07  & 0.16  & 0.03  & 0.12
        & 0.05  & 0.08  & 0.04  & 0.08  & 0.03  & 0.04              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    thailand$_{t-1}$
    &   & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.06  & 0.03  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.05  & 0.02  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.03  & 0.01              \\
    &   thailand$_{t-1}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.04  & 0.08  & 0.00  & 0.00
        & 0.03  & 0.07  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.03  & 0.06              \\
    &   thailand$_{t-2}$
        & 0.01  & 0.07  & 0.03  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.05
        & 0.04  & 0.09  & 0.02  & 0.04  & 0.03  & 0.10              \\
    \addlinespace
\mcl    mk$_{t-1}^{+}$
    &   & 0.01  & 0.07  & 0.03  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.05
        & 0.04  & 0.09  & 0.02  & 0.04  & 0.03  & 0.10              \\
    &   mk$_{t-1}^{+}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.01  & 0.07  & 0.03  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.05
        & 0.04  & 0.09  & 0.02  & 0.04  & 0.03  & 0.10              \\
    &   mk$_{t-1}^{-}\times$DC$_{t-1}$
        & 0.01  & 0.07  & 0.03  & 0.08  & 0.01  & 0.05
        & 0.04  & 0.09  & 0.02  & 0.04  & 0.03  & 0.10              \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: any suggestions to include stars significance level for the t-stat column ..

Comment: instead of `tblr` use `talltblr`, add `note{*} = {text ...}` in table preamble and in table body insert `\TblrNote{*}` where needed (if I correctly understood your comment). However, you accept other answer (so I wonder, why you ask me ), where this can also be solved but on different way ...

Comment: Actually Mico's point of view is right, but as a I'm going to interpret I need to mention where the significance level at 1% or 5% is.. that how it works for most papers..

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting that you mention "better looking variable names" as the primary (actually, sole) formatting objective for the table at hand. I would have guessed there'd be some much more pressing formattingobjectives to take care of.

Regarding variable names: I sugggest you render them in text italics and that you abbreviate `duringcovid` to `DC` in all cases. I'd also reduce the spacing between the rows.

Oh, and please do *not* use `\resizebox` unless your house is on fire right now and you therefore feel entirely free to communicate that you really, really don't care about the appearance and legibility of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% (I've streamlined the preamble as much as possible)
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 %\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo} % mathpazo is borderline archaic
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\useosf
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[hang,labelfont=bf,textfont=it,skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}

%% new:
\usepackage{rotating} % for sidewaystable env.
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{siunitx} % for S column type
\newcommand\vn[1]{\textit{#1}} % how to display variable names

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out amount of intercol. whitespace
\caption{Baseline and selected MEMs: Estimated coefficients, July 2010 to January 2020}
\label{tab:table_detailed_occ_stats}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
         l 
         *{12}{S[table-format=1.2,round-precision=2,round-mode=places]}
         }
   \toprule
   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{HK}
   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{IN}
   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{KO} \\
   \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9} \cmidrule{10-13}
   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Baseline} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Selected} 
   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Baseline} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Selected} 
   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Baseline} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Selected} \\
   \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} 
   \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} 
   \cmidrule{10-11} \cmidrule{12-13}
   &\mc{Coef}&\mc{t-stat} &\mc{Coef}&\mc{t-stat}
   &\mc{Coef}&\mc{t-stat} &\mc{Coef}&\mc{t-stat}
   &\mc{Coef}&\mc{t-stat} &\mc{Coef}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{t-stat} \\
  \cmidrule{2-13}
  $\omega$   & 0.031& 3.89& 0.05& 0.14& 0.31& 0.50& 0.03& 0.08& 0.25& 0.42& 0.03& 0.04\\
  $\mu_{t-1}$& 0.820& 0.31& 0.01& 0.01& 0.20& 0.35& 0.01& 0.02& 0.16& 0.28& 0.01& 0.01\\
  $\vn{DC}_{t-1}$& 0.06& 0.11& 0.01& 0.02& 0.05& 0.09& 0.01& 0.01& 0.05& 0.08& 0.01& 0.01\\
  $\vn{postcovid}_{t-1}$& 0.00& 0.00& 0.02& 0.10& 0.00& 0.01& 0.01& 0.05& 0.00& 0.00& 0.01& 0.02\\
  $\vn{hong kong}_{t-1}$& 0.137& 0.07& 0.00& 0.00& 0.05& 0.06& 0.00& 0.00& 0.04& 0.05& 0.00& 0.00\\
  \quad
  $\vn{hong kong}_{t-1}\times \vn{DC}_{t-1}$& 0.21 &0.11  &0.03 & 0.02& 0.20& 0.13& 0.03& 0.02& 0.18& 0.14& 0.02& 0.02\\
  $\vn{indonesia}_{t-1}$& 0.17& 0.06& 0.13& 0.04& 0.17& 0.11& 0.16& 0.08& 0.19& 0.18& 0.16& 0.14\\
  \quad
  $\vn{indonesia}_{t-1}\times \vn{DC}_{t-1}$ &0.08& 0.01&0.05& 0.01& 0.09& 0.01& 0.04& 0.01& 0.12& 0.04& 0.06& 0.03\\
  $\vn{south korea}_{t-1}$& 0.09& 0.01& 0.41& 0.19& 0.11& 0.02& 0.45& 0.27& 0.12& 0.06& 0.48& 0.34\\
  \quad
  $\vn{south korea}_{t-1}\times \vn{DC}_{t-1}$& 0.00& 0.00& 0.20& 0.12& 0.00& 0.00& 0.22& 0.13& 0.00& 0.00& 0.23& 0.17\\
  $\vn{malaysia}_{t-1}$& 0.00& 0.00& 0.05& 0.03& 0.00& 0.00& 0.06& 0.04& 0.00& 0.00& 0.07& 0.04\\
  \quad
  $\vn{malaysia}_{t-1}\times \vn{DC}_{t-1}$& 0.08& 0.01& 0.15& 0.05& 0.11& 0.02& 0.18& 0.10& 0.12& 0.06& 0.18& 0.13\\
  $\vn{malaysia}_{t-2}$&0.06 &0.01 &0.01 &0.00 & 0.07 &0.02 &0.01 &0.00 &0.08 &0.03 &0.00 &0.00\\
  $\vn{philippines}_{t-1}$& 0.01& 0.09& 0.25&0.45& 0.02& 0.08& 0.23& 0.45& 0.02& 0.06& 0.22& 0.39\\
  \quad
  $\vn{philippines}_{t-1}\times DC_{t-1}$& 0.00& 0.00&0.04& 0.09& 0.00& 0.00& 0.04& 0.12& 0.00& 0.00& 0.05& 0.14\\
  $\vn{singapore}_{t-1}$ &0.00  &0.00 & 0.06& 0.03& 0.00& 0.00& 0.05& 0.02& 0.00& 0.00& 0.03& 0.01\\
  \quad
  $\vn{singapore}_{t-1}\times \vn{DC}_{t-1}$& 0.00& 0.00& 0.04& 0.08& 0.00& 0.00& 0.03& 0.07& 0.00& 0.00& 0.03& 0.06\\
  \quad
  $\vn{singapore}_{t-2}$& 0.01& 0.07& 0.03& 0.08& 0.01& 0.05& 0.04& 0.09& 0.02& 0.04& 0.03& 0.10\\
  $\vn{taiwan}_{t-1}$& 0.01& 0.02& 0.08& 0.16& 0.01& 0.02& 0.08& 0.17& 0.01& 0.01& 0.07& 0.08\\
  \quad
  $\vn{taiwan}_{t-1}\times \vn{DC}_{t-1}$& 0.04& 0.23& 0.07& 0.16& 0.03& 0.12& 0.05& 0.08& 0.04& 0.08& 0.03& 0.04\\
  $\vn{thailand}_{t-1}$ &0.00  &0.00 & 0.06& 0.03& 0.00& 0.00& 0.05& 0.02& 0.00& 0.00& 0.03& 0.01\\
  \quad
  $\vn{thailand}_{t-1}\times \vn{DC}_{t-1}$& 0.00& 0.00& 0.04& 0.08& 0.00& 0.00& 0.03& 0.07& 0.00& 0.00& 0.03& 0.06\\
  \quad
  $\vn{thailand}_{t-2}$& 0.01& 0.07& 0.03& 0.08& 0.01& 0.05& 0.04& 0.09& 0.02& 0.04& 0.03& 0.10\\
  $mk_{t-1}^{+}$& 0.01& 0.07& 0.03& 0.08& 0.01& 0.05& 0.04& 0.09& 0.02& 0.04& 0.03& 0.10\\
  \quad
  $\vn{mk}_{t-1}^{+}\times \vn{DC}_{t-1}$& 0.01& 0.07& 0.03& 0.08& 0.01& 0.05& 0.04& 0.09& 0.02& 0.04& 0.03& 0.10\\
  \quad
  $\vn{mk}_{t-1}^{-}\times \vn{DC}_{t-1}$& 0.01& 0.07& 0.03& 0.08& 0.01& 0.05& 0.04& 0.09& 0.02& 0.04& 0.03& 0.10\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My thanks and appreciation. Please how to include statistical significance stars for t-stat column , i tried \usepackage{xcolor} with \newcommand\tc[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}} But it  seem not to work nicely

Comment: @Haithem - I think your table is already at (or even above) the upper limit for the amount of information that can be sensibly conveyed. I wouldn't overload the table even more by adding stars for various degrees of statistical significance in the table itself. Can you not reasonable expect your readers to be fully aware of the fact that a t-stat being greater than 1.96 in absolute value means that it's signficant at the 95% level (against 2-sided alternatives)?

Comment: You're quite right.!